# Multiple names for the same (local) computer

Tags: dns, ip, lan

Long story short: I need a really easy way to assign multiple names for my local computer (Windows 7 Home edition), I've tried MaraDNS/Deadwood and AcrylicDNS which I've read they are the easiest to set up, but followed the instructions on the readme and setup files over and over again and I just can't make them work, so I am frustrated.

I need a solution that doesn't involve a DNS server or otherwise a DNS server which is REALLY EASY and straight forward to set up for non experts. I could also solve my problem by having muliple IP Addresses on a single network adapter. The easiest the better.

If you wander why I want this: I have several (LAN) web sites running on my computer but since I have only one computer name, I can only access one at a time, if want to access another I need to either change the computer's name or mess with the web server configuration, which in both cases is error pron and time consuming. Yes, I've tried virtual machines, but they consume lots o memory which hinder my operation.

Comment: Can't you just allocate them to different ports?

Answer (score 3):

There are dozens of solutions.

1. You could assign more IP addresses to your NIC. (Control panel->network and sharing->change adapter settings-> right click your NIC and click properties->click IPv4, click properties->click advanced.  On the IP settings tab click add and add a new IP address.
2. You could create multiple websites with the same IP address but different ports.  To access them put in (http(s)://servername:portnumber/path) into the browser
3. You could use host headers. In IIS give all your sites the same IP address and add a DNS name to each site.  If you use DNS, create an A record for each site and give them the IP address of your computer. If you don't have internal DNS, change the hosts file on every computer that will need to access the site.  The host file is located in %Systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc. Add a row, and follow the examples.  The computers will use this before going to DNS.

Comment: Editing the hosts file an using host headers is going to be the easiest option overall.